# laravel Shopping Cart Call to a member function has() on null (0)

Tags: php, laravel

this problem occurs when I used Darryldecode\Cart
 the edit() method
    public function edit($id)
    {

```
  $product=Product::find($id);

//  Cart::add(455, 'Sample Item', 100, 2, array());


  Cart::add($id,$product->name,1,$product->price,['type'=>'PDF']);

  return back();
```

and the cart/index.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($cartItems as $cartItem)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$cartItem->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$cartItem->price}}</td>

      <td>{{$cartItem->qty}}</td>
      <td>{{$cartItem->options->has('type')?$cartItem->options->type:''}}</td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

so I have this problem and want to solve it

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to a member function has() on null

and it wants validation required 
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `optional` helper:

```
optional($cartItem->options)->has('type') ? $cartItem->options->type : ''
```

Comment: thanx very much

Comment: @MassaAl you could mark this answer as solution if it works for you - to let other people see that it works.